# Auto-copy in Google Spreadsheets whenever a cell is selected

Tags: windows-7, chrome, clipboard, google-drive

I am looking for a browser extension (preferably Chrome), script or Windows 7 program that modifies the behavior of Google Spreadsheets so that whenever a cell is selected its content is copied into the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

This userscript will auto-copy the cell's contents *once it becomes active*; it's not exactly what you want, but it does what you want at the expense of another click.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Google Sheets auto copier
// @namespace    http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/%E1%94%95%E1%96%BA%E1%98%8E%E1%95%8A
// @version      0.9
// @description  Auto copies cell contents when it is active
// @author       ᔕᖺᘎᕊ (http://stackexchange.com/users/4337810/%E1%94%95%E1%96%BA%E1%98%8E%E1%95%8A)
// @match        *://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/*
// @require      https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js
// @grant        GM_setClipboard
// ==/UserScript==

setTimeout(function() {
    $('div[class="cell-input"]').on('click', function() {
        GM_setClipboard($(this).text());
    });
}, 1000);
```

1. Install [Tampermonkey](http://tampermonkey.net/) (before you use this because the script relies on `GM_setClipboard` and Tampermonkey provides support for that).
2. [Install the script](https://github.com/shu8/SE-Answers_scripts/blob/master/Google%20Sheets%20auto%20copier.user.js)